# Adding thunderbolt port to windows laptop

Tags: windows, port, input, thunderbolt

Is it possible to add a Thunderbolt port via an adapter or some other way to a Windows laptop?

Answer (score 2):

Nope. Thunderbolt has to hook up to both PCIe x4 and DisplayPort graphics, and there aren't standard connections for those in laptops.

Comment: this is the answer. Why the person who asks the question does not mark it as an answer.